# Cannot replace header & footer using “the_content”

Tags: customization, the-content

It replace everything except header & footer. I've tried different priority for this function but it doesn't seem to work.

I think `the_content` is only for content and not header/footer, but after reading documentation, I still cannot find what else to use.

```
function add_lazyload($content) {

    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {  
        $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
        $node->setAttribute("data-src", $oldsrc );
        $newsrc = null;
        $node->setAttribute("src", $newsrc);
    }
    $newHtml = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
    return $newHtml;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
```

Comment: There is no equivalent filter for the header and footer (or the sidebar, for that matter). It appears that you're trying to change the uploads URL everywhere, but the uploads URL shouldn't be hardcoded anywhere in the header or footer. Could you please elaborate on what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: My goal is actually for lazy loading. You can click the "edited" link to see my actual function. Because the function longer and harder to understand, I'm using simpler example above.

Comment: looks like you'd probably need to output buffer the entire page from start to finish to even have a chance of doing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @majick, how else would you achieve it other than outputting the entire page to a a buffer?

Comment: @Motivated if you want to replace in between header and footer, you could try starting the output buffering at a later hook, say between the header and footer. eg. `add_action( 'wp_head', function() {ob_start();}, 999 ); add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {$contents = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); $contents = str_replace( 'something', 'something_else', $contents ); echo $contents;}, 0 );`

Comment: ...otherwise you'd need to buffer header and footer separately in a similar way, but that may or may not be reliable depending on the theme. there are many optimization plugins that buffer the entire page so this is still an okay option.